# How to explicitly stop a Google App Engine dynamic backend when the start handler finishes?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend

I have a backend that consumes a queue in its start handler.  When the queue is exhausted the start handler will stop.  I want the backend to stop when the start handler finishes.  I have other code that will send a request to the backend if it adds an item to this queue.  These requests merely serve to have GAE start the backend so that it can start consuming the queue.

I don't want the backend to ever be in a state where the start handler has finished but the backend remains idle.  I want it to stop so that the next request to the backend will cause GAE to start the backend again thus invoking the start handler again and start consuming the queue.

How do I accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 1):

Backends can't (currently) be started and stopped programmatically. It sounds like what you want, though, is a regular task queue task, which behaves exactly as described.

Comment: I chose backend because task queues are required to be idempotent and do not guarantee FIFO in all cases.

Comment: @DataSurfer But your backend is consuming a task queue - so the same caveats apply.

Comment: in this case it is not consuming a task queue, it is consuming a queue structure in the datastore, items with status=active and sorted by timestamp, as items are processed their status is set to closed

Comment: @DataSurfer ...why? We provide the task queue service for _exactly_ these sorts of jobs.

Comment: The documentation said that strict FIFO could not be guaranteed.  "_The system attempts to deliver the lowest latency possible for any given task via specially optimized notifications to the scheduler. Thus, in the case that a queue has a large backlog of tasks, the system's scheduling may "jump" new tasks to the head of the queue._"

Comment: Thanks for your patience in helping me wrap my head around App Engine.

Comment: @DataSurfer It does this for scalability and throughput - and any implementation of your own will have to compete with the same factors. Unless you have an extremely good reason FIFO is required, you should use task queues.

Comment: Is task queue processing time accounted as application CPU time or backend usage?

If it's application CPU, then using backends may be desirable since it's billed separately.

Comment: @Aleksander It's CPU time - but you can have a task queue execute against a backend if you really want.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your backend as a Dynamic backend, then the backend will stop automatically 15 minutes after your "trigger" request is processed.  If you don't send that "trigger-to-start" request again in the next 15 minutes, the backend will shutdown automatically.  Unfortunately, you'll still have to pay for a minimum of 15 minutes of uptime, even though the backend is idle for those 15 minutes.  I'm doing exactly what you're doing in my app - the backend starts, starts leasing tasks from a pull queue, and goes idle when the pull queue is empty.  I do this once every hour, so I end up paying for 24/3 = 8 hours of backend uptime everyday.  Since this is below the 9 hour quota, I'm happy (for now).